# MyBatis Insert and no return key :Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am getting exception while inserting a record in to a table using with MyBatis (MyBatis-3.1.1jar)configured via annotations.

Well the table has only two columns.

```
Table EMLSIGNUP(
employeeName varchar(25)
country varchar(25)
)
```

And I am using POJO class to insert records.

```
public class EmailBean{
private String employeeName;
private String country;
…getters and setters..
}
```

And In the mapper I am inserting like this.

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO EMLSIGNUP(employeeName,COUNTRY, ) " +
        "VALUES (#{employeeName  ,jdbcType=VARCHAR},  #{country ,jdbcType=VARCHAR})")
public void insertEmail(EmailBean emailBean);
```

The exception is

```
caused by: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Seems it’s looking for some primary key, which I have not defined in the database as well as in the POJO class and

Since its audit table we don’t want any primary key to be there in the table as user login to our application we store his name and country visited.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the extra comma:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO EMLSIGNUP(employeeName,COUNTRY ) " +
        "VALUES (#{employeeName  ,jdbcType=VARCHAR},  #{country ,jdbcType=VARCHAR})")
public void insertEmail(EmailBean emailBean);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because we were using the wrong version of jdbc drivers.

In my case, it was Oracle, we were using ojdbc for 12c whereas the database version was still 11g.

So using correct version of ojdbc fixed the issue.

Hope it helps.